# (Ubuntu 10.04) How can I get rid of installing apache2 when I install php5?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

Since i want to use nginx , i don't want install apache2

http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid-updates/php5-curl
in that link there is no dependency for apache2.

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/apt/apt.conf.d# apt-get install --no-install-recommends php5-curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common libapache2-mod-php5 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
  libaprutil1-ldap

Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec apache2-suexec-custom php-pear

Recommended packages:
  ssl-cert

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common libapache2-mod-php5 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
  libaprutil1-ldap php5-curl

0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 49 not upgraded.

Need to get 6,281kB of archives.
After this operation, 19.3MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

It is annoying, i can't get rid of installing apache2

Comment: Does uninstalling Apache then not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from your link, that package depends on `phpapi-20090626`, which is a virtual packages provided by one of `libapache2-mod-php5`, `libapache2-mod-php5filter`, `php5-cgi`, or `php5-cli`. In the absence of a reason not to, it will prefer the first one, which depends on Apache.

To get around this, manually install one of the other packages providing `phpapi-20090626`. The latter two options don't depend on Apache.

```
apt-get install php5-cli
apt-get install php5-curl
```